# Short story where a guy falls in love with a girl who turns out be a cat

Tags: story-identification

This has been driving me crazy for the past few days. I remember reading a short story a few years ago where the (if I recall correctly) the central plot twist was that this guy go together with a woman who turned out to be shapeshifter, spending her nights as a cat. Unfortunately, I can remember that many details. I believe the guy at some point commented that this woman's breath was always fishy, or something like that. At first, I thought the story was written by Neil Gaiman, but I've been looking through the various short story collections of his that I have, and I just can't find the story. Sorry I can't be more specific, as I don't remember many details about the story. 
If anyone has an idea which story this could be, I would be eternally grateful for any clue. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and feel free to [edit] in any details that come to your mind. Anything at all will help!

Comment: I believe you may be referring to the screen play for Tim Burton's Batman Returns...

Comment: Maybe "The Catswold Portal" by Shirley Rousseau Murphy?  It's been a while since I read it, but the fishy breath bit sounds familiar.  https://www.amazon.com/Catswold-Portal-Shirley-Rousseau-Murphy-ebook/dp/B000W915BC/ref=la_B000AP8YIU_1_12?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1491865915&sr=1-12

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm pretty sure it was as short story that I happened to read in an anthology.